# Incorrect using vlookup formula

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vlookup

I have in excel one table:

```
AAl 1
AAr 2
Abu 3
```

and the second

```
AAl
AAr
ABa
ABe
ABu
```

I would like have the same numbers in second table as in the first table. I am using vlookup formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(BL3;$BI$3:$BJ$5;2;0)
```

BL3 is the first row in second table and $BI$3:$BJ$5 is the first table. Unfortunately, I received:

```
AAl 1
AAr 2
ABa #N/A
ABe #N/A
ABu #N/A
```

The last row is incorrect because ABu should have number 3. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use trim, I got it using trim `=+VLOOKUP(TRIM(C5),$A$1:$B$3,2,0)`

EDIT:

I have added the screenshot which clearly shows an extra space in notepad++,

[image]

Comment: what is "+" before VLOOKUP ?

Comment: you can start formula from "=" or "+" , i was a lotus 1,2,3 user long back , it uses plus to start formula , i have the same habit till now,to support lotus users in excel, Microsoft kept the plus sign to make it userfriendly

Comment: Whao man, thanks for copying on my answer and removing your previous one saying that `Abu` was different from `ABu`.

Comment: I must accept that my earlier answer was wrong, but i haven't copied your formula. Thanks ,+1 for that

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that there are no extra spaces in your data. From your question, there seems to be spaces, so you might try:

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(BL3);$BI$3:$BJ$5;2;0)
```

hoping that the extra space characters aren't some sort of other character you can't easily see. Otherwise, remove the extra spaces manually, and you should be able to capture most invisible characters if you do a `=LEN()` on the cell and see what the character count is not correct.